# How to create a txt file on a dynamically chosen folder

Tags: c#, file

Hello, thanks for reading my question. I have a string that I need to put on a txt file.

I want to make it so that when the user clicks a button it asks for the folder, where the user wants to save this txt file, and generate it on in folder.

Here is some code I made but I do not know how to make it so that the user to chooses the folder.

```
private void Generar_Txt_Disco(string s_content, string s_folder)
{
        //Ruta es donde se va a guardar
        StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(s_folder);
        //Vas escribiendo el texto
        sr.WriteLine(s_content);
        //Lo cierras        
        sr.Close();           
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

Use the `SaveFileDialog` or `FolderBrowserDialog` for that. (Member of `System.Windows.Forms`)

> **SaveFileDialog** Prompts the user to select a location for saving a file. This class cannot be inherited.
>
> **FolderBrowserDialog** Prompts the user to select a folder. This class cannot be inherited.

#### Sample for FolderBrowserDialog

```
private static void Generar_Txt_Disco(string s_content)
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog()) 
    {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog()) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           //Ruta es donde se va a guardar
            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(dialog.SelectedPath + "\\YourFileName.txt");
            //Vas escribiendo el texto
            sr.WriteLine(s_content);
            //Lo cierras        
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sample for SaveFileDialog

```
private static void Generar_Txt_Disco(string s_content)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog()) 
    {
        dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog()) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Ruta es donde se va a guardar
            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName);
            //Vas escribiendo el texto
            sr.WriteLine(s_content);
            //Lo cierras        
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN: SaveFileDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)
- [MSDN: FolderBrowserDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)
- [MSDN: How to: Save Files Using the SaveFileDialog Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx)
- [C# SaveFileDialog Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog)

Comment: It is a good practice to dispose dialogs opened with `ShowDialog` because they are not disposed automatically when closed.

Comment: Good point, my answer is updated. Everything that implements `IDisposable` should be Disposed. Thanks

Comment: Is there a method to ask the filename too?

Comment: Sure, use the second sample. This asks for file path and name.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog ())
{
  if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    //contains the path the user picked
    string filepathToSave = sfd.FileName;

    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filepathToSave ))
      {
         file.WriteLine("foo");
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    public static string GetAnyPath(string fileName)
    {
                //my path where i want my file to be created is : "C:\\Users\\{my-system-name}\\Desktop\\Me\\create-file\\CreateFile\\CreateFile\\FilesPosition\\firstjson.json"
                var basePath = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath.Split(new string[] { "\\CreateFile" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, $"CreateFile\\CreateFile\\FilesPosition\\{fileName}.json");
                return filePath;
    }
```

replace .json with any type according to need
also can refer https://github.com/swinalkm/create-file/tree/main/CreateFile/CreateFile
for complete code